# Slice a vector in chaining operation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How to slice a vector in chaining with dplyr

```
v <- 1:10
#can be easily done with 
v[v > 5]
#use chaining 
v %>% ??
```

I'm trying to get myself used to chaining...

Comment: should also have a dplyr filter in here.

Answer (score 13):

Using this:

```
library(magrittr)
v <- 1:10
```

try any of these:

**1) extract** Use `extract` from magrittr

```
v %>% extract(. > 5)
## [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

**2) [** `extract` is a synonym for `[` so this also works:

```
v %>% `[`(. > 5)
## [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

**3) subset** This  is similar but uses `subset` instead of `extract` or `[`:

```
v %>% subset(. > 5)
## [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

**4) Filter** R provides the `Filter` function for functional programming:

```
v %>% Filter(f = . %>% { . > 5 })
## [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

**4a)** This is the same but uses ordinary anonymous function notation:

```
v %>% Filter(f = function(x) x > 5)
## [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

**UPDATE:** Have added addtional solutions, rearranged and added headings.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
v %>% .[.>5] # . represent the object (valid for list, data.frame, etc)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

Great answers, but which is faster (or at least slightly faster)?:

```
library(dplyr)
library(maggrittr)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(Base = v[v>5],
               Option1 = v %>% .[.>5],
               Option2 = v %>% `[`(. > 5),
               Option3 = v %>% subset(. > 5),
               Option4 = v %>% Filter(f = . %>% { . > 5 }),
               Option5 = v %>% subset(. > 5),
               Option6 = v %>% extract(is_greater_than(., 5)))

Unit: nanoseconds
    expr    min       lq      mean   median       uq    max neval   cld
    Base    461    727.0    822.21    785.5    880.5   1766   100 a    
 Option1  50383  53589.0  55699.46  54769.5  56297.0  76875   100  b   
 Option2  52408  56379.0  58837.53  57705.5  59769.5  76897   100  bc  
 Option3  62437  66398.5  68436.73  67941.5  69271.5  97161   100    d 
 Option4 125552 130317.0 134762.53 132480.5 135797.0 195510   100     e
 Option5  62167  66241.5  71737.07  67793.5  70266.0 267053   100    d 
 Option6  53986  57378.0  59683.31  58620.5  60410.5  91577   100   c
```

Base it's absolutely more faster, but the question is about a chain operation, so options 1 and 2 are more suitable for this purpose

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this also works with magrittr (which is lighter-weight that dplyr, which the OP tagged).

Comment: The solutions all use magrittr.  dplyr is not needed for any of them.  I would think that `v[v>5]` not using any packages would be the fastest.

Comment: Solutions 1 to 4 can be performed without using magrittr package. The question is about slice a vector inside pipes operator in a dplyr context, not about base packages nor maggrittr.

Comment: Worth noting that the difference between the best and worst times (mean) is 0.000087 seconds, and the multiplicative difference is about a factor of 2 from best to worst. I ran a benchmark comparing to `v[v > 5]` and it's about 100x faster than your winning `dplyr2` method. I would say the takeaway is: *If you care about efficiency on the order of microseconds, don't use `magrittr`. If you don't care about a few microseconds, then any of these methods are equivalent - it doesn't matter.*

Comment: @aldo, I think what you mean is that you can use library(dplyr) without using library(magrittr) but that is only because dplyr imports and exports parts of magrittr.  dplyr itself adds nothing to this.

Comment: I appreciate you adding the `base` option to the benchmark, but I still disagree with your conclusion that "1 and 2 are more suitable". None of the differences between non-base options are big enough to matter. If you care about speed, you use base. If you don't, it's just personal preference.

Answer (score 9):

Purely *magrittr*:

```
library(magrittr)
v <- 1:10

v %>% extract(is_greater_than(., 5))
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```